# Spring beans config - import order, can we use ref value of bean which is configured later in xml by import?

Tags: spring

I have the following spring beans config:

```
<import resource="a1.xml"/>
<import resource="a2.xml"/>
<import resource="a3.xml"/>
```

Can I use ref link to a bean from a3.xml in a1.xml?

For example in a1.xml:

```
<bean id="someId" class="com.xxxx.yyyy" scope="prototype">
    <property name="test" ref="%SOME_BEAN_ID_FROM_a3.xml%"/>
</bean>
```

Is it valid?

Comment: You are missing the id name in your second bean
id="" class="com.xxxx.yyyy"

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've made typo, but it's just an example, of course I have id in my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The following setup would work:

**appConf.xml**

```
   <bean id="urlPath" class="java.lang.String">
       <constructor-arg type="char[]" value="google.com"/>
   </bean>
```

**appConf2.xml**

```
<import resource="appConf.xml"/>

<bean id="urlBean" class="java.net.URL">
    <constructor-arg ref="urlPath"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Obama said:
Yes you can!
(also you are missing the id value in your second bean)

```
id="" class="com.xxxx.yyyy"
```